# How does the psmatch2 command increase sample size in Stata?

Tags: stata, propensity-scores

I first ran a regression with my dependent variable and covariates:
reg dv treatment covar1 covar2 covar4 covar5 covar6
The n=738

Then a used psmatch2 to generate new treatment/control groups according to propensity score:
psmatch2 treatment covar1 covar2 covar4 covar5 covar6, out(dv) logit

I then ran a regression with my new treatment group:
reg dv treatment covar1 covar2 covar4 covar5 covar6 [fweight=_weight]
The n=998 for this regression.

Why did the n increase after psmatch2?